# Connect java class to included xml android

Tags: android, view, include

I have a xml layout with an element i use multiple times... so i decided to use `<include>` in the xml to avoid excess code. 
My problem is that i want to make a class that is connected to this included xml component and reference to it, rather than writing the same code multiple times.

I tried to read up on a custom view component and created a class ParcelPopbarView:

```
public ParcelTopBarView extends View {

/...

public ParcelTopBarView(Context context, ParcelListItem parcelListItem) {
        super(context);
        this.parcelListItem = parcelListItem;
        this.context = context;

        titleTextView = findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
        subtitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.subtitle_textview);
        deliveryInfoTextView = findViewById(R.id.delivery_info_textview);
        thumbnailLogo = findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_logo);

    }

    public void setTopbar(){
      titleTextView.setText("hello!");  
    }
```

But i felt like custom views mostly is about drawing on a canvas, i am not doing that... so i dont know if using view is right either. 
Either way, the titleTextView is null cause it cannot find the refrence to the xml file, and i have no idea how to reference to it hahah.

Does anyone have a smart solution to how i can do this the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inflate the layout for all the constructors of your custom view to be able to access them later.

```
public class ParcelTopBarView extends View {

public ParcelTopBarView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public ParcelTopBarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public ParcelTopBarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

public ParcelTopBarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}


private void init() {
    View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.parcel_top_bar, this);

    titleTextView = findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
    subtitleTextView = findViewById(R.id.subtitle_textview);
    deliveryInfoTextView = findViewById(R.id.delivery_info_textview);
    thumbnailLogo = findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_logo);
}
```